# Wondering why my error message pops up through every name read in a file?

Tags: python, logic, file-handling

I'm making a program in Python for a class that involves logging in to get to the main GUI. Currently, this file has 3 sets of usernames and passwords. My intention was for when the user clicks a button, the program reads through all account username and password combinations from a txt file, and if it does not find a match, an error message shows up. Right now it is giving that error message after it reads each set of names. So if I try to sign in with the last account's information in the file, it will give me the error 2 times, then proceed to log in. If anyone has any advice to help fix my logic, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
def verify_login(login):
    user = login.login_window.username_entry.get()
    password = login.login_window.password_entry.get()
    accounts = open("accounts.txt",'r')
    for line in accounts.readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if (user == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]):
            print("Account found. Logging in...")
            ###
            ###  take to main gui
            ###
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Account not found. Try again.")
            login.login_window.username_entry.delete(0,END)
            login.login_window.password_entry.delete(0,END)
```

Comment: You don't want to issue an error until you get COMPLETELY through the list without finding a hit.  That means you need to have a "found" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
def verify_login(login):
    user = login.login_window.username_entry.get()
    password = login.login_window.password_entry.get()
    accounts = open("accounts.txt",'r')
    found = False
    for line in accounts.readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if (user == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]):
            print("Account found. Logging in...")
            found = True
            break
            ###
            ###  take to main gui
            ###
    if not found:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Account not found. Try again.")
        login.login_window.username_entry.delete(0,END)
        login.login_window.password_entry.delete(0,END)
```

If you `return` during the "success" processing, then you don't need the `found` flag.  Once you exit the loop, you know you have a failure.

Comment: Just to add to your solution, you could get rid of the `found` flag and instead use an else after the for loop. It will only execute if the for loop ended without a break, and so the result would be the same.